# Nested textscan statements

Tags: matlab, file-io, nested, textscan

The following two statements read the first line from an input file (`fid`) and parse said line into strings delimited by whitespace.

```
a = textscan(fid,'%s',1,'Delimiter','\n');
b = textscan(a{1}{1},'%s');
```

I would like to know if this action can be accomplished in a single statement, having a form similar to the following (which is syntactically invalid).

```
b = textscan(textscan(fid,'%s',1,'Delimiter','\n'),'%s');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
a = textscan(fid, '%s', 1, 'Delimiter', '\n');
```

you can use

```
a = fgetl(fid);
```

That will return the next line in `fid` as a string (the newline character at the end is stripped). You can then split that line into white-space separated chunks as follows:

```
b = regexp(a, '\s*', 'split');
```

Combined:

```
b = regexp(fgetl(fid), '\s*', 'split');
```

Note that this is not 100% equivalent to your code, since using `textscan` adds another cell-layer (representing different lines in the file). That's not a problem, though, simply use

```
b = {regexp(fgetl(fid), '\s*', 'split')};
```

if you need that extra cell-layer.